# How to enable serviceworker in heroku deployment using creat-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, service-worker, create-react-app, heroku-cli

I have created an app using create-react-app, which is deployed using heroku.
I have replaced the `serviceWorker.ubregister();` to `serviceWorker.register();`.
Service worker works fine when I followed the the below steps from https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

```
npm i -g serve
serve -s build -l 4000
```

I am assuming something to do with the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` but not sure how to fix this.

Code can be found: https://github.com/subhendukundu/gif-code-snippet
Hosted in: https://gif-code-snippet.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I hope you have used the correct buildpack also? `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git#v1.2.1`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I don't know I too had the same problem of ServiceWorker registration during my development of a PWA.

I think there is an issue with the *serviceWorker.js* file that comes with `create-react-app`. So I had a custom *serviceWorker.js* which was more development friendly with logs on console showing the corresponding events of the ServiceWorker. I found the below `register()` function as useful.

```
export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
}
```

Though `window.location` and `window.location.href` are both synonymous. I prefer former as `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` by default is a path and not an URL.

However I recommend you to replace your serviceWorker.js file with [this file.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kinagiabhinav/DMALab/master/serviceWorker.js)